# Booklet package - wrong ToC page numbers

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering, booklet

I am sorry if the question was asked before but I did not found anywhere any solution for this particular problem.

During the writing of a short version of my thesis, I use the booklet package. Unfortunately, I met a problem with the page numbering inside the ToC. In exact, all page numbers show (iii) which is actually a page where the ToC is placed and not correct page number of the section.
The problem disappears when I %% the "\usepackage booklet".

Since I need to submit my work till Wednesday I would really appreciate your help.

My code below.

Thanks in advance!

```latex
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[polish,czech,english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{2cm}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{2cm}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{2.5cm}
\addtolength{\textheight}{-5cm}

% orange box to emphasise undefined references
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\makeatletter
\def\@setref#1#2#3{%
  \ifx#1\relax
   \protect\G@refundefinedtrue
   \nfss@text{\reset@font\bfseries\fcolorbox{black}{Orange}{??}}%
   \@latex@warning{Reference `#3' on page \thepage \space
             undefined}%
  \else
   \expandafter#2#1\null
  \fi}


\newcommand\Affiliation{%
\Department{}\\
\Faculty\\
\University\\
\Address}

\newcommand\SupervisorAffiliation{
\Department\\
\Faculty\\
\University\\
\Address}

% % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % 
% modify/specify below as needed
% % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % 

\newcommand\DissTitle{Behavioural analysis of drivers in Czech Republic with respect to Variable Speed Limit system.}
\newcommand\TitlesBefore{Ing.}
\newcommand\FirstandFamilyName{Michał Matowicki}
\newcommand\TitlesAfter{}
\newcommand\Email{removed@for.privacy}
\newcommand\Location{Prague}
\newcommand\Month{April}
\newcommand\Year{2019}
\newcommand\PhDProgram{Engineering Informatics of Transportation and Communication}
\newcommand\Department{Department of Applied Mathematics}
\newcommand\Faculty{Faculty of Transportation sciences}
\newcommand\University{Czech Technical University in Prague}
\newcommand\Address{removed for privacy, 110 00 Prague 1, Czech Republic}
\newcommand\Supervisor{prof. Ing. removed for privacy Ph.D.}
\newcommand\SupervisorEmail{removed@for.privacy}
%-> remove comments if you have thesis co-supervisor
%\newcommand\CoSupervisor{removed for.privacy}
%\newcommand\CoSupervisorAffiliation{
%Computer Science and Engineering Department\\
%Faculty of Electrical Engineering\\
%Czech Technical University in Prague\\
%Karlovo n\'{a}m.~13\\
%121 35 Prague 2\\
%Czech Republic}

% % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % 
% uncomment the following lines to produce a booklet
% % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % 

\usepackage[print]{booklet} % final printing run
\setpdftargetpages

% % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % %
\pagenumbering{roman}

\begin{document}


\begin{titlepage}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
{\sffamily\University\\
\Faculty\\
\Department\\
\vfill
{\large\bfseries\DissTitle}\\
\bigskip
{by}\\
\bigskip
{\large\emph{\FirstandFamilyName}}\\
\vfill
Doctoral Degree Study Program: \PhDProgram
\vglue 1cm
\ifx\PhDSpecialization\undefined\relax\else{Specialisation: \PhDSpecialization}\fi
\vfill
Dissertation thesis statement for obtaining \\ the academic title of ``Doctor'' abbreviated to ``Ph.D.''
\vglue 1cm
\Location, \Month~\Year}
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}


\newpage
{\footnotesize
\noindent The dissertation thesis was written during full-time doctoral study at the \Department, \Faculty{} of the Czech Technical University in Prague.
\vglue .5cm
\noindent\hbox to 3cm{\hbox{Ph.D. Candidate:}\hss}\parbox[t]{8cm}{\FirstandFamilyName\\
\Affiliation\\
\Email
}
\vglue .5cm
\noindent\hbox to 3cm{\hbox{Supervisor:}\hss}\parbox[t]{8cm}{%
\Supervisor\\
\SupervisorAffiliation\\
\SupervisorEmail}
\vglue 1cm

\noindent\hbox to 3cm{\hbox{Reviewers:}\hss}\parbox[t]{8cm}{%
\vrule width 5cm height 0pt depth 0.5pt\\[.5cm]
\vrule width 5cm height 0pt depth 0.5pt\\[.5cm]
\vrule width 5cm height 0pt depth 0.5pt
}
\bigskip\bigskip

\noindent The dissertation thesis statement was distributed on April 19, 2019.
\bigskip

\noindent The defence of the dissertation thesis will be held before the Committee for the presentation and defence of the dissertation thesis in the doctoral degree study program Engineering Informatics of Transportation and Communication \ifx\PhDSpecialization\undefined\relax\else{in the \PhDSpecialization{} specialisation}\fi\\ 
on June 14th 2019 in the Department of Applied Mathematics the meeting room No. 3 .
\bigskip

\noindent In accordance with Para. 8 of Art. 30 of the Study and Examination Regulations for Students of the CTU, those who are interested may look into the dissertation thesis and make notes, copies, or duplicates from it at their own expense. A copy of the dissertation thesis is available in the Science and Research Office of the \Faculty{}, room No. K210.

\begin{center}
\bigskip
\bigskip
prof. Ing. Zdeněk Votruba, CSc.\\
\medskip
Chairman of the Committee for the presentation and defence of the dissertation thesis
\ifx\PhDSpecialization\undefined\relax\else{\\ in the \PhDSpecialization{} specialization}\fi\\
% \Department\\
\Faculty\\
\University\\
Konviktská 20, 110 00 Praha 1, Czech Republic 
\end{center}}
%\newpage

\tableofcontents

\cleardoublepage

%\pagestyle{headings}\pagenumbering{arabic}\setcounter{page}{1}

\section{Introduction and Motivation}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
The need for deployment of Intelligent Transport Systems in a modern transport network is a widely accepted fact nowadays. A simple idea behind it is that there is no more space for further construction of wider road...
\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance again.

Comment: Compile with the booklet code commented out and then compile again with the booklet code and the command `\nofiles`. That way no new `.toc` file will be generated but the old (correct) one will be used instead.

Comment: If you want a clean solution: Set your document without any booklet code and use [pdfjam](https://warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/statistics/staff/academic-research/firth/software/pdfjam) afterwards to produce a booklet